# jQuery causing browser to timeout when lots of sortables

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a feature in my software that allows users to edit multiple items at once. They can choose what items they want and each one is placed in a column. I've then created a drag and drop interface to copy data from each item.

Problem is, I have to load a sortable for each column. If they choose 10 columns, it loads a heck of a lot of sortables which is causing the browser to hang and bring up a message in FireFox asking if I want to stop the script from running. This is obviously because browsers have a limited javascript execution time.

Is there a way I can make jQuery sortables load without causing the browser to hang?

Not sure if it'll help but my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".servicesMultipleMembers").sortable({
        connectWith: '.servicesMultipleMembers',
        placeholder: 'servicePlaceHolder',
        containment: '#servicesMembers',
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            moving_li_index_members = $(this).find('li:hidden').index();
            $(this).find('li:hidden').show();
        },
        remove: function(event, ui) {
            var newRow = $(ui.item).html();
            var newRowRel = $(ui.item).attr('memberId');
            var newRowTarget = $(event.target).find('li:eq(' + (moving_li_index_members) + ')');
            if ($(newRowTarget).length == 0) {
                $(event.target).append('<li memberId="' + newRowRel + '">' + newRow + '</li>');
            } else {
                newRowTarget.before('<li memberId="' + newRowRel + '">' + newRow + '</li>');
            }
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
                        var newRowImg = $(ui.item).find('span.serviceTitle img').attr('src');
            var newRow = $(ui.item).html();
            newRow = newRow.replace(newRowImg, site_url + 'img/help.png');
            newRow = newRow.replace('<span class="member_declined">', '<span class="">');
            $(ui.item).html(newRow);
            MultipleServices.checkServicesMembersConflicts($(ui.item));
            update_member_stop = true;
        },
        update: function(event, ui) { // Only update if reordering list
            if (!update_member_stop && $(event.target).attr('id') == $(ui.item).parent().attr('id'))
                MultipleServices.updateServiceMembers($(ui.item).parent());
            update_member_stop = false;
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a demo or something we can look at? Might help in coming up with an alternate way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would try doing something with setTimeout and a recursive function.  maybe something like this:

```
function initSortable(idx) {
    if ($(".servicesMultipleMembers").eq(idx).length >0) {
        $(".servicesMultipleMembers").eq(idx).sortable({
            connectWith: '.servicesMultipleMembers',
            placeholder: 'servicePlaceHolder',
            containment: '#servicesMembers',
            helper: 'clone',
            start: function(event, ui) {
                moving_li_index_members = $(this).find('li:hidden').index();
                $(this).find('li:hidden').show();
            },
            remove: function(event, ui) {
                var newRow = $(ui.item).html();
                var newRowRel = $(ui.item).attr('memberId');
                var newRowTarget = $(event.target).find('li:eq(' + (moving_li_index_members) + ')');
                if ($(newRowTarget).length == 0) {
                    $(event.target).append('<li memberId="' + newRowRel + '">' + newRow + '</li>');
                } else {
                    newRowTarget.before('<li memberId="' + newRowRel + '">' + newRow + '</li>');
                }
            },
            receive: function(event, ui) {
                            var newRowImg = $(ui.item).find('span.serviceTitle img').attr('src');
                var newRow = $(ui.item).html();
                newRow = newRow.replace(newRowImg, site_url + 'img/help.png');
                newRow = newRow.replace('<span class="member_declined">', '<span class="">');
                $(ui.item).html(newRow);
                MultipleServices.checkServicesMembersConflicts($(ui.item));
                update_member_stop = true;
            },
            update: function(event, ui) { // Only update if reordering list
                if (!update_member_stop && $(event.target).attr('id') == $(ui.item).parent().attr('id'))
                    MultipleServices.updateServiceMembers($(ui.item).parent());
                update_member_stop = false;
            }
        });
        setTimeout(initSortable(idx+1),500);
    } else {
      //remove loading message logic goes here
    }
}
```

and then in the document .ready event: `initSortable(0);`

the set timeout should give the browser some breathing room, though you will probably want some indication of work in progress on the page.

Comment: Awesome that's perfect! I'm working on showing an overlay loading message to indicate it is loading like you mentioned. However, when the page loads, it hangs and doesn't show my loading message until the sortables have a loaded... Is there any way to force load my loading overlay function first?

Comment: i'm not sure how you have it implemented, so i can't really say, but i would make sure to initialize it first, before calling initSortable(), and then add an else to initSortable() to turn off the loading message.  i've updated the answer to have the else statement.